# Asking Question Guildine

Tags: discussion

new to this forum and I would like a quick bit of guidance (which doesnt seem to be covered by the site FAQ). I have a question I would like to ask but I can see that it has already been asked and answered from over several years ago now. I believe my question is dependant on time though and the answer may have changed since it was originally asked. How do I correctly go about asking such a question.

Comment: @Byte56 But then you answered him below! ;)

Comment: @Vaughan yep, the whole thing, including answer, should be moved to meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to handle this is to [open a bounty](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) on the question. Unfortunately, this is not an option for new users. You can either wait until you have enough reputation (75) to open a bounty or a higher rep user may be willing to open a bounty on the question for you to get an updated answer. You will need to include a link to the question for that to happen.

Comment: This is the question - gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/394/network-layer-libraries. Was asked several years ago.

Comment: @CanCan Ah, that likely won't be one that would be good to get going again. That question is sort of considered off topic these days. Since it's a "which technology to use" question.

Comment: Is there anywhere to ask that sort of question?

Comment: Yes. Check out the [FAQ]. That will give you a list of sites where you can ask discussion oriented questions.